# file not created on host after mounted

Tags: docker, ubuntu

With `docker container inspect xxx`, I can find the mount information.

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/deploy/app/log",
            "Destination": "/home/applog",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

After `docker exec -it xxx bash`, the `/deploy/app/log` directory is there and the file in it is also updated.
However, the `/home/applog` directory is not created on the host and I double checked the source it's right eg. `deploy/app/log`

This question is quite close to my situation, since the answer talking about mount with directory would solve that, means not my problem.
[Files within Docker bind mount directory not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547973/files-within-docker-bind-mount-directory-not-updating)

My assumption is about writing privilege.Any idea on how to troubleshooting on this situation?

### UPDATE：

[See full command of running/stopped container in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380641/see-full-command-of-running-stopped-container-in-docker)
Find `COMMAND` is `"/usr/bin/supervisord"`

### UPDATE:

The server is using CentOS.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9b7127d72e8cdf42b7bf7ec1e6559d2d9c02eb0deb197375c084532a8e4f443c",
        "Created": "2018-11-15T09:22:42.498258742Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/supervisord",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 19508,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-02-19T08:17:25.738865995Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-02-19T08:17:25.484443245Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:02079d9230e89eeb1eb14d61ab299da9e0301abed90864655087a39c3010a222",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9b7127d72e8cdf42b7bf7ec1e6559d2d9c02eb0deb197375c084532a8e4f443c/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9b7127d72e8cdf42b7bf7ec1e6559d2d9c02eb0deb197375c084532a8e4f443c/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9b7127d72e8cdf42b7bf7ec1e6559d2d9c02eb0deb197375c084532a8e4f443c/hosts",
        "LogPath": "",
        "Name": "/prime",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/deploy/app/log/:/home/primelog/"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "journald",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "isolated_nw",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "90"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "docker-runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay2",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/705a362229df9caa92a7df72427890ea99ab01f04fc0d3056e55d50f69fe0214-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/83e113da8135ee896fa64413cfbc5198c6414d556e002e5f5d398e3615683a0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/334a1f552eb25e0fec63bf12e2c3a0cbf168b3ddee22c9349d935557b3ec1e40/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6745c1ba399830b8f2b8c4bcce5704093dab7342bb97e57ad6c7de666c2a7923/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a4721324b462df2f6197206ebd61c803f75ea1ea8d9a3a15d6876a4439c359c0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ab1ee75afa757ccba6d744c0b773e75e8d0d064f367496cc1dc9c140800303a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae19ae7d9c4878438bfe3d80c8a7be32304df2e9af95f851f1d5fa9636c555f5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c01c124469518c189dd1384f81e7d887fa5ee5cd46c368b67fa75285fad61a7a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3bdec856fe714fb865d6bdb3e2d2b5512aac8c5eed8c20c00416a92159b0469b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae4bdc4a37252da3326f81ed8536f4c536aa59d6b46a1e198893c0aa816a3bda/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ecab217632d4c34bbafb098755855d0f5861fd21a4df809f1c16081a08a33865/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5958ffc7e373cf927b181010d3d40b2bac384f7d45253842dc7316022f4c8ff/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bd73e0cc649d72fcb1eaabf582ba948b34d5e91f43d1ce1a9dd54192beecde26/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3cfccc6f5782f0e83be600097aa6d9f0da0d2bd978ffd4f36c97060fad7352c8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0efa6e2c8dfa6529c1ce891406e5c3be1559809d05d0efafd789453615c2e50/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/87959f4181e90b251956cf864095821dce34b8e4f925713c2de1e029e11c5b6b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2fae884b115fe56f6e04de3df4391501d0bb694f2ec3b8c4189c5519642231e1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ec08c775e3bf6968bb67bf7713313f7d9bad5c29dc49baddb623d5bc0c5218f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d37caccf87df38f4ffee6fcd9b96c81fd323d52e3a1eeb85d75babf9f0b59ac6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f7c20c7f13cc18c86de6f7c8f574a2a123b06e0e1f65a18eca7981e601ed819/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2055cc3e03990255615e9843b9e5df2e5a9d5fd44b65bc83fc867611bd67a538/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/913548c1650469d344bbe8eb41a824669b6665c2aa8c2ac08ded95324314597f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b3eae5e3b2adba7114d823d2321b272c59f5ae58408ce1e88c97eb98614873e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b466e47668a96fdb8c1a622c30a827c9c0073448ddcfbe57fb3d2be5fa8881c4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ffef761f24efe242c032951ef1bf10134bb1a541bd66b04d3f3c934d03c14b32/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/705a362229df9caa92a7df72427890ea99ab01f04fc0d3056e55d50f69fe0214/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/705a362229df9caa92a7df72427890ea99ab01f04fc0d3056e55d50f69fe0214/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/705a362229df9caa92a7df72427890ea99ab01f04fc0d3056e55d50f69fe0214/work"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/deploy/app/log",
                "Destination": "/home/primelog",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "9b7127d72e8c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "DEMS_ENV=product",
                "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D",
                "PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.0",
                "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=18.0",
                "PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/usr/bin/supervisord"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "primetmr",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/deploy/app",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "author": "wrui",
                "purpose": "= "
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "2a9cfc3d58b56ede602075d4e39f3d7fb3597b0db4bf8ea1f0c5dccd625d8972",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "90"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/2a9cfc3d58b5",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "isolated_nw": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "9b7127d72e8c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "2b169058c11e359b8add8d7cd7949936039dae21f6b0a0dbf26e6ed83df8422b",
                    "EndpointID": "fe83ca9952dadc80278adba7f96095be542a565139ba24ff6f63cdf486d62775",
                    "Gateway": "172.25.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.25.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:03"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the run command you're using to spin up your container, or the docker-compose section that's used to initialize it?  Also, what storage driver are you using?  I'm assuming the default.

Comment: @MichaelMiller how can I find out the run command? It's a running container. Not using the docker compose. The storage driver? No idea, probably default.

Comment: It's whatever you typed in to make the container run...

Comment: @MichaelMiller if it's not started by the same user, how to find out?

Comment: The docker image, entrypoint and command will do.  You can get all of this from docker inspect.  I'd just post the entire JSON output from `docker inspect`.

Comment: You're still not posting enough information about what's going on...  I use supervisord in one of my own docker deployments...  Supervisord can assign users to processes.  In order to troubleshoot, we'd need to know the user assigned to the process managing /home/applog, the operating system you're running on, the users assigned to the processes that supervisord is using to manage /home/applog, the user docker is assigning to /home/applog (I'm assuming it's root), etc.  We've got almost nothing to work with here.

Comment: @MichaelMiller Updated the docker inspect infomation. Assumming it's root(almost sure, but don't know how to verify.)

Comment: Do you have the supervisord configs?  This is likely where your answer is going to be.

Comment: @MichaelMiller I tried `find supervisord.conf` not file founded. But I'm sure the `Destination /home/primelog` should be in the host, and the `Source deploy/app/..` is right in container.

Comment: I don't see any mention of /home/applog in the JSON inspection listed above...  I see "/home/primelog".  Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, that was changed by me manually when paster to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find on official site https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

> The source of the mount. For bind mounts, this is the path to the file
>   or directory on the Docker daemon host. May be specified as source or
>   src.
>   The destination takes as its value the path where the file or
>   directory is mounted in the container. May be specified as
>   destination, dst, or target.

They are wrong ordered in the `docker run` command.